# Counter example to show that $\sup(A∩B)=\max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$ is not true?

Tags: real-analysis

For some reason I am struggling to find a counter example. Intuitively, I know the equation is not true because at most we can say is $\sup (A \cap B) \leq \min(\sup A, \sup B)$ since $\sup E \leq \sup F$ for all $ E \subset F$. But how do I think of a concrete example to show that the equation is false?

Comment: Is the "max" in the title supposed to be a "min"?

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure. I was given Sup(AUB)=max{sup E, sup F} and I was asked if there was an equivalent statement for $sup (A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $A = (0,2)$ and $B = \{-1, 1, 2\}$?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused with my understanding of sup. Wouldn't that be Sup(A)=2, Sup(B)=2 but $ sup(A \cap B)$ = 2? Would something like A = [1, 3] and B = [1, 2]. work? Where Sup (A)=3, Sup (B)=3, $sup(A \cap B) = 1?$

Comment: $A \cap B = \{1\}$, so $\sup(A \cap B) = 1$. Note that $2 \not\in A$ and hence can not be in $A \cap B$. Also, if $A = [1,3]$ and $B = [1,2]$, then $A \cap B = [1,2]$ and hence $\sup(A \cap B) = 2$.

Comment: Oh I see now! Sorry, I misread A as A={0,2}. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The "reasonable but false" thing to expect would be $\sup(A \cap B)=\min \{ \sup A,\sup B \}$, since taking intersections makes the set smaller so it makes it easier to bound it above. (Maybe this was a typo.)

An extreme case where this breaks is where $A,B$ are nonempty and disjoint, in which case you have $\sup \emptyset=-\infty$. There are similar examples where the overlap between the two sets is entirely below their suprema, for instance $A=(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and $B=(0.5,1.5)$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! The original question was that  given Sup(AUB)=max{sup A, sup B} and I was asked if there was an equivalent statement for sup(A∩B).I blindly assumed it would be the maximum, but I'm glad you pointed out my error!